# Multidimensional array, find key of chosen value

Tags: php, html

I have a code with an array containing a bunch of fruits with product id and price as keys for the different values.

I get the correct price, but how do I get the name of chosen product? For example if you choose the "apple 1", I want the answer to be "The product apple costs 5.95" where it now just says "The product costs 5.95". As you may see, I've tried to do an array_search without good results.

How should I do this?

```
<?php
$a3 = array('apple' => array('productid' => '1',
                            'price' => '5.95'),
            'banana' => array('productid' => '2',
                            'price' => '122'),
            'squash' => array('productid' => '3',
                            'price' => '47.2'),
            'watermelon' => array('productid' => '4',
                            'price' => '1.2'),
            'potato' => array('productid' => '5',
                            'price' => '6.04')
            );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="products">
        <?php
         foreach ($a3 as $key => $value){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['price']; ?>"><?php echo $key, " ", $value['productid']; ?></option>
        <?php
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="showprice" value="Show the price">

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['showprice'])){
                $price = $_POST['products'];
                $product = array_search("$price", $a3);

                echo "The product ". $product ." costs ". $price .".";
        }
    ?>

</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest set the value of your dropdown like productname_price so whenever you fetch the value you can simply explode it with '_' and get both productname and price. This will save your looping time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *option* value shoud be a key. Because products price can be same then eachother. I mean when you post the form, your post variable need to be unique value "*apple*". Then you can get the product node from the array.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="products">
        <?php
        foreach ($a3 as $key => $value){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $key, " ", $value['productid']; ?></option>
            <?php
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="showprice" value="Show the price">

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['showprice'])){
        $name       = $_POST['products'];
        $product    = $a3[$name];
        $price      = $product['price'];
        $productid = $product['productid'];
       echo "The product ". strtoupper($name) ." costs ". $price .".";
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes! I did it in the wrong direction. By using the key as option value instead, so I could get the price with $a3[$product]['price'], where $product is the value of the select name.

Answer (score 2):

As per your array, i think there is no need to use `array_search()`, you can also concatenate the `$key` with product value as:

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
  <select name="products">
    <?php
    foreach ($a3 as $key => $value){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value['price']; ?>-<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $key. " ". $value['productid']; ?></option>
    <?php
    } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="showprice" value="Show the price">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST['showprice'])){
  $data = explode('-',$_POST['products']);
  $price = $data[0];
  $product = $data[1];
  echo "The product ". $product ." costs ". $price .".";
}
?>
```

Using concatenation for `<?php echo $value['price']; ?>-<?php echo $key; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

This array_search function doesn't work as expected when you have this kind of a multi dimensional array. You could try and write a custom search function like this on top of the page:

```
function multiDimSearch($price, $arr){
    foreach ($arr as $fruit => $val) {
        if ($val['price'] == $price) {
            return $fruit;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then change:

```
 $product = array_search("$price", $a3);

   To

 $product = multiDimSearch($price, $a3);
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['showprice'])){
                $price = $_POST['products'];
                $product = "";
                foreach($a3 as $k=>$a) {
                    if($a['price'] == $price) {
                        $product = $k;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                echo "The product ". $product ." costs ". $price .".";
        }
    ?>
```